# VBA e HTML - alterar um combobox

Tags: html, microsoft-excel, vba, combobox

Preciso de uma programação em VBA que:

1. Entre no *site* http://www.bmfbovespa.com.br/shared/iframe.aspx?altura=400&idioma=pt-br&url=http://www.bmfbovespa.com.br/pt-br/mercados/acoes/cotacoes/boletim-diario/BoletimDiario.asp
2. Altere o `combobox` de acordo com o valor da célula B2 da planilha
3. Atualize a página

Estou utilizando o código abaixo, mas sem sucesso.

---

```
Public ie As InternetExplorer
Dim objCollection As Object
Dim element As IHTMLElement
Dim elements As IHTMLElementCollection    

Public Sub internet()
Workbooks("Copy of teste.xlsm").Worksheets("Plan1").Select

dia = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 2)

Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium

ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate "http://www.bmfbovespa.com.br/shared/iframe.aspx?altura=400&idioma=pt-br&url=http://www.bmfbovespa.com.br/pt-br/mercados/acoes/cotacoes/boletim-diario/BoletimDiario.asp"

Call IEWait(ie)

ie.document.getElementsByName("cboData")(0).Value = dia


End Sub
```

Comment: O que acontece quando executa esse código? Algum erro? Senão, consegue jogar o conteúdo do document para uma celula e analisar?

Comment: Na ultima linha, aparece o erro:
A variavel do objeto ou a variavel do bloco With nao foi definida